# Is there a way to disable Visual Studio for prompting to upgrade an older solution file?

Tags: visual-studio, project, upgrade

Is there a way to disable Visual Studio for prompting to upgrade an older solution file?

I'm opening the project in VS2010, yes I want you to actually open it, and no I don't want your backup.

Is there some way I can permanently bypass this and just have this work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44060441/241296

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have limited options here.  You could start devenv.exe with the /upgrade command line option to perform an upgrade.  That just upgrades the solution and doesn't actually start the IDE.  The backup is always made without an option to skip it.  Useful in batch conversion scenarios.  Copied from the console window:

```
C:\projects\ConsoleApplication7>devenv /upgrade consoleapplication7.sln

Microsoft (R) Visual Studio Version 10.0.40219.1.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.

Upgrade completed successfully. Results can be seen in the
upgrade report:
C:\projects\ConsoleApplication7\UpgradeLog.XML
```

Comment: Figured it was a feature I couldn't opt out of =/