# Add custom xml lines to project

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I’m generating projects for unix and windows with cmake. For win we use certain version of vs build tools, which are a bit outdated already. As a result each time I launch generated project, I get project upgrade prompt, which is quite useless.

I’ve found that [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38787635/how-to-prevent-visual-studio-to-prompt-to-upgrade-projects-net-4-to-net-4-5/44060441) on how to disable it via certain oneliner:

```
<VCProjectUpgraderObjectName>NoUpgrade</VCProjectUpgraderObjectName>
```

The question is how do I insert it into project during cmage gen process.